# Spring Boot SimpleDiscoveryClient YAML configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I have a microservice `serviceA` that uses feign client to access another microservice.

During development, I want to rely on `SimpleDiscoveryClient` to get an instance of the service running in my docker daemon. If I configure `spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.serviceA[0].uri=http://localhost:8081` then SimpleDiscoveryClient recognizes the `serviceA` and feign client works.

If I try to configure `SimpleDiscoveryClient` using `yaml` as below it doesn't recognize the service:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            serviceA:
              - uri: "http://localhost:8081"
```

This doesn't make sense to me.

I don't want to have an application.properties and application.yml just for that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Instances is a list, not a map

Comment: Thank you for your replay @spencergibb, how would I write this configuration in yaml format?

Answer (score 1):

For the record please find a working example. I came across this question when trying to figure out the right configuration format.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            backend-service:
                - uri: http://localhost:9090
                - uri: http://192.168.110.50:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            serviceA[0]:
              uri: http://localhost:8081
```